# How do I configure loginctl lock-sessions with i3?

Tags: systemd, i3, loginctl

Currently, I'm using i3 with `xscreensaver`. I would like to configure `loginctl` such that `lock-session` and `lock-sessions`. How is this supposed to be done?

```
lock-session [ID...], unlock-session [ID...]
    Activates/deactivates the screen lock on one or more sessions, if the
    session supports it. Takes one or more session identifiers as arguments.
    If no argument is specified, the session of the caller is
    locked/unlocked.

lock-sessions, unlock-sessions
    Activates/deactivates the screen lock on all current sessions supporting
    it.
```

Answer (score 0):

`light-locker` plays nice with `loginctl` so I'd suggest installing that and adding something like this to your xsession:

```
light-locker --lock-on-suspend --lock-on-lid --lock-after-screensaver=30 &
```

Then you can also configure a shortcut in `.i3/config`:

```
bindsym $mod+l exec light-locker-command --lock
```